# Why does requesting the "estimated execution plan" for sp_delete_job throw an error?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I'm attempting to look at the estimated execution plan for the following T-SQL statement:

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job @job_id = '3A015189-F4EB-439B-9CA0-27AFB74719D8'
    , @originating_server = '(LOCAL)'
    , @delete_history = 0
    , @delete_unused_schedule = 0;
```

When I do that, SQL Server throws the following error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_delete_all_msx_jobs, Line 25
>
> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

The definition of `sp_delete_all_msx_jobs` contains the following pertinent lines starting at line 25 (wrapped for readability):

```
INSERT INTO #temp_jobs_to_delete
SELECT sjv.job_id, 
    CASE sjs.server_id WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    sjv.owner_sid
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs_view sjv
    LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers sjs 
        ON (sjv.job_id = sjs.job_id)
WHERE (ISNULL(sjs.server_id, 0) = 0)
    AND (sjv.originating_server = @msx_server)
```

Line 14 of that stored proc shows the definition of `#temp_jobs_to_delete` is:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete 
(
    job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL
    , job_is_cached INT NOT NULL
    , owner_sid VARBINARY(85) NOT NULL
)
```

That looks valid to me.  Why is "Display Estimated Execution Plan" returning an error?

I can run this on SQL Server 2008R2, and 2012; both return the error.  I'm using SSMS 2012.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like there are two conflicting definitions of `#temp_jobs_to_delete`.

One comes from `sp_delete_job`:

```
-- Note: This temp table is referenced by msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job_references,
-- so it cannot be declared as a local table.
CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete (job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                                   job_is_cached INT NOT NULL)
```

And the other comes from `sp_delete_all_msx_jobs`:

```
-- Delete all the jobs that originated from the MSX
-- Note: This temp table is referenced by msdb.dbo.sp_delete_job_references
CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete (job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
    job_is_cached INT NOT NULL, owner_sid VARBINARY(85) NOT NULL)
```

I can reproduce the error with the following simplified script:

```
CREATE PROC #test1 AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete (
        job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        job_is_cached INT NOT NULL
    )

    IF (GETDATE() < '1/1/2015') -- Always false
        EXEC #test2

    DROP TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete
END
GO

CREATE PROC #test2 AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete (job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
        job_is_cached INT NOT NULL, owner_sid VARBINARY(85) NOT NULL)

    INSERT INTO #temp_jobs_to_delete
    SELECT NEWID() AS job_id, 0 AS job_is_cached, 0x1234 AS owner_sid
END
GO

-- This statement runs successfully, but fails to compile when viewing an estimated plan
EXEC #test1
GO
```

I think that what is happening is that SQL Server uses the definition of the first creation of `#temp_jobs_to_delete` to try to compile the remainder of the plan. In fact, I can't see anywhere in `sp_delete_job` (or the procs it calls) that would drop `#temp_jobs_to_delete` prior to invoking `sp_delete_all_msx_jobs`. I could be missing something, but it seems like you would also get a run-time error if you invoke the procedure with a value for the  `@originating_server` parameter, thereby causing the `sp_delete_all_msx_jobs` procedure to have to be invoked.

```
-- Do the delete (for all jobs originating from the specific server)
IF (@originating_server IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_delete_all_msx_jobs @msx_server = @originating_server
```

Note that the `@originating_server` parameter has the following comment and [Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188376.aspx) specifies that it is for internal use only.

```
@originating_server sysname = NULL, -- Reserved (used by SQLAgent)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because Microsoft hasn't learned to create unique object names. If you look at the definition for `sp_delete_job`, you will find this around line 115, a slightly different version of `#temp_jobs_to_delete`:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_jobs_to_delete (job_id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
                                   job_is_cached INT NOT NULL)
```

Now, consider that SQL Server may take a slightly different path when generating *estimated* execution plans for a set of nested procedure calls than if it simply ran the code. It likely does some kind of object-level collection that recognizes the same #table is used and assumes that it must adhere to the same schema (even if logically the two #temp tables would never cross paths).

Now, it is possible that this code will actually break when you try to delete a job and the properties of that job lead to `sp_delete_all_msx_jobs` to be called, which I suspect in your case did not happen on actual execution (nor in mine). I did not have the energy to set up MSX to evaluate. But remember some of the other things that happen during parsing that couldn't possibly be a problem on actual execution:

```
IF (1 = 1)
  CREATE TABLE #x(i INT);
ELSE
  CREATE TABLE #x(d DATETIME);
```

Illogical parsing error:

> Msg 2714, Level 16, State 1
>   
> There is already an object named '#x' in the database.